# How to add map markers stored in SQLite? - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have latitude and longitude coordinates stored in an sqlite database. I am trying to retrieve these via cursor and place them all on a map. I'm trying my best, but I am new to developing and need a little help. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class allmapactivity extends MapActivity {
MapController mControl;
GeoPoint GeoP;
MapView mapV;
private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
    mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapV.setSatellite(false);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapV.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll5();

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.valueOf(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT11) *1E6),(int) (Double.valueOf(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT12) *1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Test", "Test");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);



}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

All of this code works when I enter static numbers for my geopoint, except when I try to add data from my cursor it force closes. Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what is going wrong as the code you provided doesn't take data from the cursor.

Generally speaking you should always call the code below before reading from any cursor.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

This is because it is not guaranteed to be pointing to a row that is NOT NULL.

If you can provide more code and/or error messages it might be easier to determine exactly what is going wrong.